# Defining class of controller at run time

Tags: ios, controller

1. What i am trying to do is to switch between the controller classes.
   [image]
2. When app launch initially the controller get load with CLASS_A & on click of button i want to reload controller with CLASS_B. Again on click of button (define in CLASS_B) reload controller with CLASS_A.
3. BOTH controller CLASS_A & CLASS_B are tableview controller.
4. **Queries:**

A. I thought this is achievable but was not able to find any good direction. Can you please direct me on this.

B. is what i am trying to do is called posing?

Comment: A clarification question: Are you asking how to make controller B appear when you are at controller A and vice versa?

Comment: No, The View(TableViewControlle) is only one. Initially the controller for the view is CLASSA. On click of one button  i want the controller of that view to be CLASSB & vice versa. Please let me know in case requires more description. Thank You for your support.

Comment: Hi @wain, This is totally an different question as compared to Objective C: is Posing available for ios? Reason: This question reference is given in is Posing available for ios? to explain why i am trying to  implement posing and more interested in knowing about posing. But in this question i am trying to implement something which may be implemented other than posing (Which is very well expanding in your answer in s Posing available for ios?). Thank You

Comment: Technically we could switch the answer to the other question here and then the other question is a duplicate of swizzling questions, either way one should be removed to keep things tidy. I opted for keeping the other one open as it has a lot more people interacting.